# C Binary Operator & (-1)

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

Suppose you have code including:

```
if(i & (-1)) {}
```

Depending on `i`, what would this operation return?

Comment: If `i`is integer, the mask as no effect, as `-1` bits are all 1s

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: This depends on the implementation/architecture.

Comment: There is not enough information given in the question for a correct answer.

Comment: @Olaf I agree. that's why I commented. Signed/unsigned/sizeof i makes a difference. I'd say this is bad coding

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: I did not talk about `i`, but `-1`.

Comment: those are trick questions, I stay away from answering them :)

Answer (score 3):

There's no definitive answer to this question: it depends on the type of `i` and, if the operation is performed in the domain of signed type, on the signed representation used by the given platform.

For example, if `i` is of type `unsigned int` (or some larger unsigned type), the entire operation will be performed in the domain of that unsigned type. In that case `-1` will get implicitly converted (by *usual arithmetic conversions*) to all-ones bit pattern as wide as `i`. The whole `if` will effectively become equivalent to `if (i)`.

But with `i` of signed type - there's no way to say anyhting for certain.

Comment: I'm really not sure if this should be better a comment, as the question indeed cannot be answered. In dubio +1.

Comment: I don't see how this can be better answered given the question.

Comment: @Alex Lop: They are defined once you know the bit-pattern. But the mapping between bit-patterns in signed integer objects and actual integer values is implementation-defined. To this day C supports 1's-complement, 2's-complement and signed-magnitude representations. Also, formally it is possible to obtain a potential trap represenaton using bitwise operations (like "negative 0" on 1's-complement and signed-magnitude, or `1000...0` on 2's-complement)

Comment: Thanks! To clarify, `i` would be an **unsigned int**.

Answer (score 1):

The results of performing a bitwise operation on a negative value are implementation defined.

For example, if 2's complement representation is used for negatives, the value -1 will be represented by a sequence of all 1 bits, so performing a bitwise AND with -1 will result in the value of `i`.

On the other hand, if sign magnitude representation is used, only 2 bits are set in the value -1, the highest and the lowest.  In that case, only the highest and lowest bits of `i` (after any conversions) will be set in the result.

So to summarize, you can't depend on the results without some implementation defined method of determining the representation of negative values.

Comment: Thanks! To clarify, `i` would be an **unsigned int**.